# Pass a value from View to action in another controller(using Viewmodel)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass a value from my current view to action method in another controller. I have used ViewModel to pass the values of both the classes. But now I want to pass a particular value from the viewmodel class as a parameter for the action method Create  in another class.

**Create Action method**

```
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id;
        ViewBag.DataFormatID = new SelectList(db.DataFormat, "DataFormatID", "FormatName");
        ViewBag.TCID = new SelectList(db.TC, "TCID", "TCName",id);
        return View();
    }
```

**model classes**

```
public class TC
{
    public int TCID { get; set; }
    public string TCName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TCSet> TCSets { get; set; }

}

public class TCSet
{
    public int TCSetID { get; set; }
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
  //  public string DataFormat { get; set; }
    public DataUsage DataUsage { get; set; }
    public DataStatus DataStatus { get; set; }
    public int TCID { get; set; }
    public int DataFormatID { get; set; }
    public virtual TC TC { get; set; }
    public virtual DataFormat DataFormat { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewTCSet for a particular TCID**

```
    public ActionResult ViewTCSet(int ?id)
    {
        var viewmodel = new TC_TCSet();

        if(id!=null)
        {
            ViewBag.TCID = id.Value;
            var tcSet = db.TC.Include(x => x.TCSets).FirstOrDefault(x => x.TCID == id);
            if(tcSet!=null)
            {
                viewmodel.TCSet = tcSet.TCSets;
            }
        }
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

View for ViewTCSet

```
@model TCImplementation.ViewModels.TC_TCSet
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewTCSet";
}
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Tc Set Name</th>
    <th>Data Usage</th>
    <th>Data Status</th>
    <th>Data Format</th>

</tr>
@foreach(var item in Model.TCSet)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ValueName</td>
        <td>@item.DataUsage</td>
        <td>@item.DataStatus</td>
        <td>@item.DataFormat.FormatName</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "TCSets", new { id= item.TCSetID},null) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "TCSets", new { id = item.TCSetID }, null) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "TCSets", new { id = item.TCSetID }, null)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "TCSets", new { id = Model.TCSet }, null)
```

In this actionlink I am unable to pass the value `Model.TCSet.TCID`
I am looking for a work around!
Vini

Comment: i cannot acces the variable that way.

Comment: But what i want to achieve is to pass the `TCID` value bound with the `TCSet`

Comment: @JayMee : TCSets is an ICollection of TCSets. Described in the model class for TC

Comment: And i am not getting any errors in the program. Only that I am unable to work my create link in the ViewTCSet to pass the id of the TC that was used to call ViewTCSet

Comment: Sorry . i wasnt aware about this fact. Thanks for the info.

Comment: you cannot pass complex type this way

Comment: and in Create case Id would be **null** or **0**, you don't need to pass that

Comment: But in my create i have used the value for id to set the value of my foreign key (TC). So i need to pass the value and i cant find out how

Comment: is there a way i can pass complex type to the controller?